# How to power on dummy virtual machine using pyvmomi python

Tags: python-2.7, vmware, pyvmomi

I created dummy virtual machine, which does not have any operating system.

Is there any way to power it on?

Thanks,
@!@Y

Answer (score 0):

**PowerOnVM_Task** this method of vm object works well with dummy vm as well.